# How to add html after the first <li> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="box">
   <ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <a class="add">test2</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Above my HTML content coming dynamic. I want to add li tag in my `test2` anchor link in JQUERY.

Here I have tried-

```
$('.box .test li:first-child').after('<li>');
```

But this li tag creating in wrong place. But I want my output should be like this -

```
<div class="box">
   <ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <li><a class="add">test2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are closing <li> and after that you are trying to insert some html that DOM wont accept

Comment: use $('ul.test .add').replaceWith('<li><a class="add">test2</a></li>');

Comment: starting html is invalid...`<a>` can't be child of `<ul>`

Comment: You want your list element to surround your existing <a> tag?

Comment: @charlietfl I think that's the point of the question

Comment: @Phil fine but can't fix it after the fact either, browser will reject it

Comment: `Above my HTML content coming dynamic` - whatever is dynamically creating that content is doing it wrong - fix that, or show us what creates your content dynamically so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and correct way would be to fix your source html! A `a` tag inside a `ul` element is not valid. So your first task should be to get a correct html output.

If not possible you could use a `:not` selector and `wrap()`. So every child element, which is not a `li`, will be wrapped with a `li` element. This keeps it dynamic ...

```js
$('ul > *:not(li)').wrap('<li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <a href="#" class="add">test2</a>
    <strong>test3</strong>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: some browsers will not render the invalid tags nested in original parent. All these wrapping solutions are wrong and will have inconsistent results

Comment: True. But they can handle it also and after the script it renders fine. You're right, that is not a good practice, but will work. @charlietfl

Comment: Please tell me which browser will not. All I've tested now (ie, ff, chrome) workes fine. @charlietfl

Comment: haven't played with this much in modern browsers.... older IE was notorious for rejecting invalid nesting...and even modern browsers get strict with table elements. Whole concept is just not  guaranteed reliable even if it works in some

Comment: Can you say what is diffrence between `$('ul > *:not(li)')` and `$("a.add")` (@RahulPatel answer) in result of code that you posted new answer?

Comment: @Mohammad I even descriped that the selector in my answer. It is more dynamic and secure selector. It only selects direct children which are not a `li` and don't need a `class` too. Assume `<li><a class="add">test</a></li>` and the selector `a.add` will become `<li><li><a class="add">test</a></li></li>`.

Comment: @eisbehr am a bit surprised but can certainly come up with numerous tag combinations that would be not work consistently cross browser. As general rule fixing source is best solution

Comment: @charlietfl I'm completly with you! Fixing the source is the right/best way. But the question was how he can fix this with JS. So my answer is not wrong. But I will edit it and add a note to change the source. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your initial HTML, since an `a` element can't be a direct child of a `ul` element. Try to fix this in you initial rendering, and **not later using javascript**, simply for the reason that different browsers will act differently upon invalid HTML fragment (auto-fix it, drop it, you name it...).

Having said that, in general `$('selector').wrap('<wrapperElement />')` is the traditional jQuery's way of wrapping an existing element with a newly created one.

Answer (score -1):

Below code will wrap li tag around a tag having class add.

```
$("a.add").wrap("<li>");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.add").wrap("<li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
   <ul class="test">
    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>
    <a class="add">test2</a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You should have more specific `selector`

Comment: You can't fix invalid html once browser has already rejected it

Answer (score -3):

you're actually looking to add an element as a parent of another one, use Jquery wrap function instead:

```
 $(".add:eq(0)").wrap("li")
```